Doubt in Hopf's Lemma
This is a problem from Evans' PDE book:

Assume $u$ is connected. Use (a) energy methods and (b) the maximum principle to show that the only smooth solutions of the Neumann boundary-value problem:
$$\begin{cases}
    -\nabla^2 u=0 \quad \text{in $U$}\\
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu }=0 \quad \quad\:\: \text{on $\partial U$}
\end{cases}$$
are $u\equiv C$ for some constant $C$

I argued like this:
a) Let $v$ be a smooth function. By Stokes Theorem and employing the identity $\nabla \cdot (\nabla u) v+\nabla u \cdot \nabla v=\nabla \cdot (\nabla u v)$ yields:
$$0=\int_U \nabla^2 u vdx=-\int_U \nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx+\int_{\partial U} v\nabla u  \cdot \nu dS=-\int_U \nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx$$
Taking $v=u$ teaches us that $\Vert \nabla u\Vert_{L^2(U)}=0$ and by smoothness this implies $\nabla u=0$. Finally using the fact $U$ is connected yields that $u\equiv C$ in $U$.
b) If $L=-\sum_{i,j}a^{ij} u_{x_ix_j}$ with $a^{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ it is clear that the result is an elliptic equation as $I$ has all positive eigenvalues. Because $Lu=0\leq 0$ If $u$ is not constant, the maximum is attained in the border in $x^0$ and so $u(x^0)>u(x)$ for all $x\in U$.
If we assume a $C^2$ boundary, there is a tangential ball at $x^0$ and by Hopf's Lemma, this implies that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}>0$ which is a contradiction.
QUESTION: I think Evans wanted us to argue like this in part b, but he only assumes that the boundary is $C^1$. At the end of Hopf's lemma he remarks there is a tangential ball to $U$ if the boundary is $C^2$. As I understand the $C^2$ condition is equivalent to asking the existence of a function $\gamma: \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is $C^2$ such that :
$$B(x^0,r)\cap \partial U=\{x\in B(x^0,r)\:|\: x_n>\gamma (x_1,...,x_n)\}$$
Even if we assume a $C^2$ boundary, how does this allow me to conclude there is a ball contained in $U$ tangential at $x^0$?
EDIT: I have found a ball lying inside $U$, but not touching $x^0$ yet... Let $\gamma$ be defined as in the question. We define:
$$f(x_1,...,x_{n})=\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})-x_n$$
We notice that points in $x\in U$ satisfy $F(x)<0$. Let me define $B=B(x^0-\varepsilon Df(x^0), \varepsilon^2)$ the ball centered at $x^0-\varepsilon Df(x^0)$ and of radious $\varepsilon^2$. By the Taylor expansion centered at $x^0$, we have that if $y\in B$ and $h=y-x^0+\varepsilon DF(x^0)$, $|h|<\varepsilon^2$ and:
$$f(y)=Df(x^0)(h-\varepsilon Df(x^0))+$$
$$D^2f(x^0)(h-\varepsilon Df(x^0))(h-\varepsilon Df(x^0))+r(h-\varepsilon Df(x^0))=$$
$$-\varepsilon|Df(x^0)|^2+Df(x^0)(h)+D^2f(x^0)(h,h)$$
$$-2\varepsilon D^2f(x^0)(h,Df(x^0))+\varepsilon^2Df(x^0)(h,h)+r(h-\varepsilon Df(x_o))\leq$$
$$-\varepsilon |Df(x^0)|^2+\varepsilon^2\left(|Df(x^0)|+|D^2f(x^0)|\varepsilon^2-2|D^2f(x^0)||Df(x^0)|+|Df(x^0)|\varepsilon^4+\frac{r(h-\varepsilon Df(x^0))}{\varepsilon^2}\right)$$
Clearly $|h-\varepsilon Df(x^0)|\leq \varepsilon(1+|Df(x^0)|)$, so:
$$\frac{r(h-\varepsilon Df(x^0))}{|h-\varepsilon Df(x^0)|^2}\frac{|h-\varepsilon Df(x^0)|^2}{\varepsilon^2}\leq\frac{r(h-\varepsilon Df(x^0))}{|h-\varepsilon Df(x^0)|^2}(1+|Df(x^0)|)^2\xrightarrow[]{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} 0$$
Hence, for $0<\varepsilon$ small we have found that:
$$f(y)\leq -\varepsilon|Df(x^0)|+\varepsilon^2M$$
As $|Df(x^0)|$ is positive (the last coordinate is actually $1$), for $\varepsilon$ small enough, it seems the ball $B=B(x^0-\varepsilon Df(x^0), \varepsilon^2)$ will lie in $U\cap B(x^0,r)$. However, this is not enough as I wanted the ball to touch $x^0$

What is Hopf’s lemma, and why the differential geometry tag?

@TedShifrin, I only want to know a property about a $C^2$ surface, namely that a ball can lie inside it and touch the boundary at a prescribed point…

I have added a partial try which is off by a factor of $\varepsilon$ not sure how to make it right... For any $x_o\in \partial U$ I wanted $B(y,r)$ to be inside $U$ and touch $x_o$ in $\partial B(y,r)$....

This sounds like a convexity assumption on the boundary, which — yes — requires that the boundary be $C^2$.

Even if I assume $C^2$ I still cannot prove this convexity like assumption... Too sad, will try again tomorrow though, it is a bit late here...

This can be reduced to the fact that a small ball can be placed tangent to a parabola at the origin.
If a function is $C^2$ you can touch it from above with a paraboloid by Taylor's theorem (which is also what you use). I'll work in the case where the boundary is a 1-D curve. By translation and rotation, we can assume that the point of interest is the origin, that the curve is horizontal at the origin, and that the second derivative is nonnegative at the origin (with the interior of $U$ lying above the origin). Then the Peano form of Taylor's theorem says that
$$
f(x) = ax^2 + R(x)x^2 = (a + R(x)) x^2
$$
with $a = \frac{1}{2}f''(0) \geq 0$ and $\lim_{{x \to 0}} R(x) = 0$. Then consider the parabola $g(x) = 3ax^2$. Then the curves of $f$ and $g$ intersect at the origin. (Let's assume $a > 0$ for now.)
Furthermore, there is an interval around the origin on which $g(x) \geq f(x)$. This is because, by the Peano form of Taylor's theorem above, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x| < \delta$, then $R(x) \leq a$ (for instance). Therefore on $(-\delta, \delta)$, it holds that
$$
f(x) \leq 2ax^2 \leq 3ax^2 = g(x),
$$
as claimed. Thus, we have found a parabola tangent to the curve which lies inside the region.
If $a = 0$ then $f(x) = R(x)x^2$. Then consider $g(x) = x^2$; this has the desired properties (the same properties that $3ax^2$ has). In this case, too, we find a parabola tangent to the curve lying inside the region.
It remains to show that, given a parabola $g(x) = Ax^2$ (without loss of generality let $A > 0$), we can find a ball tangent at the origin. There's probably a quick way to do this but it's escaping me now.
Also apparently there's just a formula for this in 1D: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle#Cartesian_coordinates.
